# Is Confluent required for JDBC source and sink connectors?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

Do I need to use `Confluent` specifically for Kafka JDBC source and sink connectors, or can I use default apache Kafka implementation? I tried to start connect-standalone with a JDBC source config as a worker property but getting the below exception:

`Failed to find any class that implements Connector and which name matches io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector, available connectors are: PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSinkConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSinkConnector', version='2.8.0', encodedVersion=2.8.0, type=sink, typeName='sink', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSourceConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSourceConnector', version='2.8.0', encodedVersion=2.8.0, type=source, typeName='source', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorCheckpointConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorCheckpointConnector', version='1', encodedVersion=1, type=source, typeName='source', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorHeartbeatConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorHeartbeatConnector', version='1', encodedVersion=1, type=source, typeName='source', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorSourceConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorSourceConnector', version='1', encodedVersion=1, type=source, typeName='source', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockConnector', version='2.8.0', encodedVersion=2.8.0, type=connector, typeName='connector', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSinkConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSinkConnector', version='2.8.0', encodedVersion=2.8.0, type=sink, typeName='sink', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSourceConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSourceConnector', version='2.8.0', encodedVersion=2.8.0, type=source, typeName='source', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.SchemaSourceConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.SchemaSourceConnector', version='2.8.0', encodedVersion=2.8.0, type=source, typeName='source', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSinkConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSinkConnector', version='2.8.0', encodedVersion=2.8.0, type=source, typeName='source', location='classpath'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSourceConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSourceConnector', version='2.8.0', encodedVersion=2.8.0, type=source, typeName='source', location='classpath'}`

I have a plugin directory looking like the following (downloaded the plugin from Confluent):
[image]

And my standalone.bat looks like the following:
[image]

Comment: Did you restart the worker after installing the plugin?

Comment: yes, i did. i'm not sure whats the issue here and why its not able to read these jars.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, Confluent Platform is not required.

In Windows, you need a double backslash for filepaths in property files - e.g. `C:\\kafka\\plugins`. Also make sure the line doesn't have trailing spaces

Also note that Kafka isn't really tested all too well on Windows, so you might want to [try WSL2 instead](https://www.confluent.io/blog/set-up-and-run-kafka-on-windows-linux-wsl-2) (yes, this is to the Confluent blog, but same steps can be followed with regular Apache Kafka downloads)